# Fetch dates within the next 5 days from today, from a column of dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with dates from last year:

```
ID  start_date
1   2020-09-06 11:21:00
2   2020-10-12 01:43:00
3   2020-09-07 17:22:00
4   2020-11-23 04:23:00
5   2020-09-09 19:50:00
```

If today is `2020-09-05`

I need to fetch rows which start_date +1 year are in the next 5 days from today.

From the sample table, the desired result would be:

```
1   2020-09-06 11:21:00 (Because 2020-09-06 +1 year = 2021-09-06 is in within 5 days from today)
3   2020-09-07 17:22:00 (Because 2020-09-07 +1 year = 2021-09-07 is in within 5 days from today)
5   2020-09-09 19:50:00 (Because 2020-09-09 +1 year = 2021-09-09 is in within 5 days from today)
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT ID, start_date 
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
DATE( "start_date +1 year" ) >= NOW()
AND
DATE( "start_date +1 year" ) <= NOW("+5 days")
```

But it is not working. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INTERVAl to get the dates you need

> ```
> SELECT ID, `start_date`
> FROM my_table 
> WHERE 
> DATE(`start_date` + INTERVAL 1 YEAR)  >= CURDATE()
> AND
> DATE(`start_date` + INTERVAL 1 YEAR)  <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 5 DAY
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | start_date         
> -: | :------------------
>  1 | 2020-09-06 11:21:00
>  3 | 2020-09-07 17:22:00
>  5 | 2020-09-09 19:50:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ee7705e6b32a3cd49001e318e462b28)*